# Is it possible that the one boat is behind the other one?

Tags: analytic-geometry

We have the equations $g_1: (4,14,-5)+t(2,-3,0)$ and $g_2:(11,9,-15)+t(-2,-3,2)$ on which two boats move at time $t$. We have the point $P(12,11.5,0)$.

Is it possible that the one boat is behind the other one when we look from the point $P$?

Do we have to find the equation of the line between $P$ and $(2,-3,0)$ and check if there is a t such that $g_2$ is on that line?

Comment: What is $12|11$ and $5|0$?

Comment: I mean $P(12,11.5,0)$ @Dave

Comment: Is my idea correct? Or do we have to do something else? @Dave

Comment: In what sense do you mean "behind"?

Comment: I understand it like that: We are on the point P and we want to know if at some point the one boat is behind the other one, so if we take the line between P and the one boat the other boat should also be on that line... But I am not really sure.   @JohnD

Comment: You also need the condition that one of the boats is between the viewpoint and the other boat. If $P$ is between the two boats, I wouldn’t consider one boat being behind the other in the view from $P$.

Comment: How can check that condition? @amd

Comment: Once you have a set of colinear points, just compare their coordinates. In [Anonymous’ solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2500080/265466), this condition is equivalent to $\lambda<0$ or $\lambda>1$.

Comment: Ah ok! Thank you!! :-) @amd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to do this for the point $(2,-3,0)$. Rather you need to consider three points $P, P_1(t), P_2(t)$ and find whether there is a value of $t$ for which these three lie on a straight line. $P_1, P_2$ lie on $g_1, g_2$ respectively and are the points associated with time $t$.

There are two procedures you might consider. The first is to compute the line joining $P_1(t)$ and $P_2(t)$ and then test the condition for $P$ to lie on that line.

The second would be to find the point $Q_2$ at which the line joining $P$ and $P_1(t)$ meets $g_2$ - this will be associated with a time $s$. Then test the condition for $s=t$.

Comment: For the first procedure: We have $P_1(4+2t , 14-3t , -5)$ and $P_2(11-2t , 9-3t , -15+2t)$. A line through these two points is $P_1+s(P_2-P_1)$, right? We don't have to use here the variable t, right?

Comment: You also need the condition that either $P_1$ or $P_2$ lies between the other two points. Colinearity alone can produce the configuration $P_1PP_2$.

Comment: @MaryStar In fact, you *shouldn’t* use $t$ as the parameter for the line through $P_1$ and $P_2$

Comment: Thanks a lot!! :-)

Comment: @amd "Of course" you need $P$ in the right place, and thanks for your comments. But I hope OP has worked out how to do the equations, which is interesting in itself. One of my comments on this type of question is quite often "draw a diagram".

Comment: @MaryStar Glad to be of assistance and I hope amd's comments helped too. I hope we didn't give you too much help, because it is thinking about these things which (a) helps you to think like a mathematician; and (b) helps you to solve similar problems when you don't have people to ask. Most people on this site want you to succeed in both of these things. I certainly do.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\exists\;t |\; \vec{g}_1+\lambda(\vec{g}_2 - \vec{g}_1) = \vec{OP\;}
$$
$$
\vec{g}_2 - \vec{g}_1 = (11-4,9-14,-15+5)+t(-2-2,-3+3,2-0) =(7,-5,-10)+t(-4,0,2)
$$
$$
\vec{g}_1+\lambda(\vec{g}_2 - \vec{g}_1) = (4,14,-5)+t(2,-3,0)+\lambda((7,-5,-10)+t(-4,0,2)) = (4+7\lambda-4t\lambda+2t,14-3t-5\lambda,-5-10\lambda+2t\lambda)=(12,11.5,0)
$$

Comment: Evaluate again: $t=2.5$, $\lambda=-1$ works.

Comment: Thank you very much!! :-)